# Why pass a parameter to $uibModalInstance.close(parameter)?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

When calling `$uibModalInstance.close(parameter)` I understand that it closes the current modal window.

But what does the `parameter` inside the `close()` method do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you open a modal it will return an object with several promises, one of those promises is `result`, this promise will be resolved when you call `close` with the parameter given to it.

```
var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
    controller: function($uibModalInstance) {
        $uibModalInstance.close('testParameter');
    }
});

modalInstance.result.then(function(parameter) {
    console.log(parameter); // logs 'testParameter'
});
```

A common pattern is to have a save/confirm button in your modal, and handling the result in the result success. To cancel the action (reject the result promise) you can call `$uibModalinstance.dismiss(reason)`